# Sending SMS Without SMS Gateway in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to send Sms on one number every time when the user clicks the button in my application.I don't want to use any Sms Gateway.The Message can be send with the Phone mobile carrier network.I Could not find it any docs.

Can Any body help me with the docs and the sample code.

Help is appreicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, which is outside of MobileFirst Platform:

1. Use the `sms://` protocol and launch the system messaging application and send it
2. Use available 3rd party Cordova plugins

This may require to take care of the whitelisting in Cordova to allow it.

Comment: Idan is there any other way given by worklight or the sample code for implementing it with cordova..Thanks for the reply

Comment: There should be custom Cordova plugins (entirely out of MFP)  . Eg:
https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

Comment: Idan can you help me in Integrating third party Cordova plugin with IBM Worklight V 6.2. Actually i am not able to clear things through the documentation given..Thanks in Advance..I want to know the steps from the beginning how to integrate the third party Cordova Plugin..

Comment: Go ahead and read: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/